# How to set logo of Authy account using Google Authenticator?

Tags: google-authenticator, authy

Is there a way to set the logo of an account on Authy using Google Authenticator automatically? I'd like this to occur after scanning a QR code. I am currently only able to do this manually.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. How would Authy use Google Authenticator?

Comment: @philnash well basically you can use both google authenticator or authy if you generate qrcode using google chart API when you scan a code using authy it automatically set the logo as default blue i was looking if is it possible to set it as default black logo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Authy application has some built in logos for well known applications that provide their own TOTP secrets, normally via scanning a QR code.

For applications that don't have a built in logo, Authy gives users the option to choose the colour of a generic logo, between black, blue, green, orange, purple and red.

There is no way to influence the colour of the generic logo that Authy offers the user by default. The QR codes you generate use [this URI format](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format) which give applications all the information they need to store a TOTP secret in the application, but there is no affordance for suggesting a logo or colour.

For an alternative, you can use [the Authy API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api) to generate your TOTP secrets and send codes via SMS or the app. That way you can choose a logo to appear in the Authy app too.

Let me know if that helps at all.